# BEMIT: Use helpers all the time vs. extend them in components vs. repeat them in components?

Tags: css, bem, itcss

I'm using the [BEMIT](https://csswizardry.com/2015/08/bemit-taking-the-bem-naming-convention-a-step-further/) (BEM + ITCSS) methodology in a project. BEMIT allows you to use helpers ("utilities") such as `.u-hidden` to hide an element.

I have a system where any numeric value (`font-size`, `margin`, `padding`, etc.) can only be a multiple of a base unit. I've created a mixin that generates margin and padding helpers automatically, based on that base unit (`.u-margin-top-8`, `.u-margin-top-16`, etc.) this way I can easily space elements without having to create a specific rule for that.

Yet, when I'm creating a component (in the [ITCSS](https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/) fashion) and I need a specific element to always have, let's say a `margin-left` of `16px` (which is the same rule as my `.u-margin-left-16` helper), I'm wondering what's the best thing to do:

1) Use the helper class in the HTML

```
// SCSS
$spacing-unit: 8;

.u-margin-left-16 {
    margin-left: #{$spacing-unit * 2}px;
}

.c-block {
   &__element {
       ...
   }
}

// HTML
<div class="c-block">
    <div class="c-block__element u-margin-left-16">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

- **upsides:** no additional CSS to write
- **downsides:** has to be repeated in the HTML every time

2) Extend the helper class in the component's code (with `@extend`)

```
// SCSS
$spacing-unit: 8;

.u-margin-left-16 {
    margin-left: #{$spacing-unit * 2}px;
}

.c-block {
   &__element {
       @extend .u-margin-left-16;
   }
}

// HTML
<div class="c-block">
    <div class="c-block__element">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

- **upsides:** component can be used out of the box, reuses existing rule
- **downsides:** generated CSS can cause rule order issues

3) Repeat the code regardless of existing classes

```
// SCSS
$spacing-unit: 8;

.u-margin-left-16 {
    margin-left: #{$spacing-unit * 2}px;
}

.c-block {
   &__element {
       margin-left: #{$spacing-unit * 2}px;
   }
}

// HTML
<div class="c-block">
    <div class="c-block__element">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

- **upsides:** component can be used out of the box
- **downsides:** repetitive code

I get that using helpers can be considered a conflicting concept with using components (BEM's blocks) as one favors composition and the other one favors inheritance, but BEMIT sounds like a nice middle ground. Yet, the articles about it never cover that one specific aspect, and I wondered what other people who have been confronted to the same issue think about it.

Comment: In the second solution, can you provide an example of "order issues"?

Comment: Hey, it's a known fact that extend [may "change" the intended order of your selectors](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-extend-nobody-told-you/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest with a mixin:

```
// SCSS
$spacing-unit: 8;

@mixin u-margin-left-16 {
  margin-left: #{$spacing-unit * 2}px;
}

.u-margin-left-16 {
  @include u-margin-left-16();
}

.c-block {
  &__element {
    @include u-margin-left-16();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you make a mixin then you can't use u-margin-left-16 as a class in HTML elements.

Comment: @SarahDayan Yes, you can. You could read my code before to comment.